# jQuery slider works but it's hard-code, how to make it dynamic

Tags: jquery

I have a list with some list items ["web","crossplatform", etc]

And i have some divs with the same classes.

**Example:**

```
 <div class="web"></div>
```

What i did is that if "web" is clicked on the list than show div with the class "web" and hide all other divs but not the list.

I have made this and it works but it's all hard-code and i want it to make more dynamic.

Here is a link to my code: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bw5vuh3a/)

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item active">web</li>
      <li class="list__item">crossplatform</li>
      <li class="list__item">wearables</li>
      <li class="list__item">tv</li>
      <li class="list__item">tablet</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="web">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit voluptatum alias exercitationem soluta, voluptatem, quod ratione dicta sequi quibusdam quam itaque veritatis similique, aspernatur id possimus quae suscipit animi aperiam?</p>
        </div>

        <div class="crossplatform">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
        </div>

        <div class="wearables">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
        </div>

      <div class="tv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
        </div>
      <div class="tablet">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .slider{
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      width: 600px;
  }
  .list{
    top: 40px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 400px;
  /*   background-color: #cacaca; */
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .list__item{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .list__item::before{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00a4ff;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform .35s;
  }

  .active.list__item::before{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  .web{
      color: red;
  }

  .crossplatform{
      color: #0F5738;
  }

  .wearables{
      color: green;
  }
.tv{
  color: #68113F;
}
.tablet{
  color: #042037;
}
  .crossplatform,
  .wearables,
  .tablet,
  .tv{
    display: none;
  }
```

**jquery:**

```
  $(".list__item").click(function(){
        var link = $(this).text();  
        var activeList = $('li').hasClass("active");

      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).siblings('.list__item').removeClass('active');

        if(link === "web" && activeList){
          $(".web").delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
          $(".wearables").hide();
          $(".crossplatform").hide();
          $(".tv").hide();
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".tablet").hide();

        }else if(link === "crossplatform" && activeList){
          $(".crossplatform").delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".wearables").hide();
          $(".tv").hide();
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".tablet").hide();

        }else if(link === "wearables" && activeList){
          $(".wearables").delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".crossplatform").hide();
          $(".tv").hide();
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".tablet").hide();

        }else if(link === "tv" && activeList){
          $(".tv").delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".crossplatform").hide();
          $(".wearables").hide();
          $(".tablet").hide();

        } else if(link === "tablet" && activeList){
          $(".tablet").delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
          $(".web").hide();
          $(".crossplatform").hide();
          $(".wearables").hide();
          $(".tv").hide();
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide all children of slider and then show the one by using the `link` variable in the class selector.

However because you probably don't want it to be depended on a text of a button so I added a data-content attribute to the `li` items so you can set the correct selector there. This way you can change the button text without breaking the code.

```js
$(".list__item").click(function() {
  //retrieve the content data attribute instead of the button text so you can change the text without breaking code.
  var contentSelector = $(this).data('content');
  var activeList = $('li').hasClass("active");

  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.list__item').removeClass('active');

  //Hide all children and then display the one belonging to the clicked button.
  $('.slider').children().hide();
  $(contentSelector).delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 600px;
}

.list {
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 400px;
  /*   background-color: #cacaca; */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list__item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list__item::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00a4ff;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .35s;
}

.active.list__item::before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.web {
  color: red;
}

.crossplatform {
  color: #0F5738;
}

.wearables {
  color: green;
}

.tv {
  color: #68113F;
}

.tablet {
  color: #042037;
}

.crossplatform,
.wearables,
.tablet,
.tv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <!-- Added data-content attribute to use as a content selector -->
    <li class="list__item active" data-content=".web">web</li>
    <li class="list__item" data-content=".crossplatform">crossplatform</li>
    <li class="list__item" data-content=".wearables">wearables</li>
    <li class="list__item" data-content=".tv">tv</li>
    <li class="list__item" data-content=".tablet">tablet</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="web">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit voluptatum alias exercitationem soluta, voluptatem, quod ratione dicta sequi quibusdam quam itaque veritatis similique, aspernatur id possimus quae suscipit animi aperiam?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="crossplatform">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="wearables">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tablet">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis, nemo voluptatibus dolor voluptate officiis iure quisquam? Quo omnis et eum adipisci inventore, porro laboriosam fugiat, quod recusandae ab, culpa accusamus?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you a million times, this is a elegant solution.

Comment: @VenRus Glad I could help, if this fully answers your question then please accept it as an answer so other people don't see your question it as an open question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
const available_class_names = [
  'tablet',
  'web',
  'crossplatform',
  'wearables',
  'tv'
];

function showOnly(show_class_name) {
  available_class_names.forEach(function(class_name) {
    var elem = $('.' + class_name);

    if (!elem.length) {
      console.log('element does not exist');
      return;
    }

    if (class_name === show_class_name) {
      elem.delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      elem.hide();
    }
  });
}
```

You would then call `showOnly(link)` instead of going through all that if/else logic.

FYI: I first define the available class names and do not dynamically do it using the `link` variable because this is "safer". Imagine that the `link` variable can contain something the user has influence on, then he might be touching elements that you do not want him to touch.